# python regex for finding all matches

Tags: python, regex

I have a sequence

```
seq = 'CCGATGACCTCACAGCCGCCTCCTGCCTTGAGGAAAGGAACTGCAATTCC'
```

I am try to get sequences of length 23bp ending with NGG where N = A or C or T or G`

I use `p = re.compile('([ACGT]{21}GG)')` and when I say

```
for m in p.finditer(seq):
      print m.group()
```

I get only `CACAGCCGCCTCCTGCCTTGAGG`.

But clearly `CCGCCTCCTGCCTTGAGGAAAGG` also matches. Why is it not reported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your regex inside a lookahead assertion in-order to do overlapping matches. Your regex fails to match the two strings because by one match contains another match . Regex by default won't do  overlapping match. You need to put the pattern inside lookarounds in-order to capture the overlapping matches.

```
(?=([ACGT]{21}GG))
```

**Code:**

```
>>> seq = 'CCGATGACCTCACAGCCGCCTCCTGCCTTGAGGAAAGGAACTGCAATTCC'
>>> p = re.compile(r'(?=([ACGT]{21}GG))')
>>> for m in p.finditer(seq):
        print m.group(1)


CACAGCCGCCTCCTGCCTTGAGG
CCGCCTCCTGCCTTGAGGAAAGG
```

See the captures at the right side in [this](https://regex101.com/r/iX8pE7/5) demo.

Comment: *Overlapping Matches*, troubling programmers since ages

Comment: pls no one come with this `(?<=([ACGT]{21}GG))` regex :)